# How to fill in missing values to show age at a specified date

Tags: sas, ssas

I am looking to find the age of a person when comparing multiple different dates in years. I have the persons age on their first record at a specific date but I want to find their age at multiple following dates in years.
My dataframe is something like this

```
data;
input ID date age ;
dataline;
1  10/27/2004   21  
1  02/04/2006   .
1  12/08/2009   .
2  07/25/2007   24
2  08/31/2008   .
2  08/27/2012   .
run;
```

I tried this but it rearanged my data & only added to the first age variable of each ID. I thought of maybe using RETAIN as well but did not have any luck using that either.

```
data want;
set have;
by age;
if first.id then age1=first.date-date+first.age;
run;
```

Comment: You cannot have a FIRST.ID or FIRST.DATE if neither ID nor DATE is one of the BY variables.  And FIRST. flags are BOOLEAN (zero or one) flags, not copies of values.  What is formula you want to use to guess the interpolated age?  Do you want to guess a birthday based on the first age that is present? Calculate the number of years between the two dates?  Either way you need to assign the value you want to remember to a variable that is retained.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to calculate the age dependent on previous values I would recommend calculating the birth_year and using that going forward.

Use RETAIN to hold the birth_year across the rows and then use it to calculate the age when age is missing.

```
data have;
    input ID date : mmddyy10. age;
    format date date9.;
    datalines;
1  10/27/2004   21  
1  02/04/2006   .
1  12/08/2009   .
2  07/25/2007   24
2  08/31/2008   .
2  08/27/2012   .
;
    ;
    ;;
run;

data want;
    set have;
    by id;
    retain birth_year;

    if first.id then
        birth_year=year(date) - age;

    if missing(age) then
        age=year(date) - birth_year;
run;
```

FYI your data step doesn't run as posted. Please test it before posting.